# Could life as we know it exist if there were no speed limit and no special-relativistic effects?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

My perception based on reading popular-science articles is this:

1. Nothing can exceed speed of light in vacuum
2. Speed of light is the same for all observers, irrelevant of their own relative speed

But my understanding, perchance completely misguided, is that these things matter mostly when we deal with huge velocities, approaching light speed - so not something organisms on earth deal with in their slow lives. I understand also that motion of planets in our solar systems can largely/roughly be described by Newtonian mechanics. I do acknowledge that relativistic effects need to be taken into account in various pieces of actual technology used by humans but they seem to be just minor error-reducing corrections.

So, taking all this into account - can Earth-like or our-solar-system-like thing exist in a world where electromagnetic waves have no speed limit and behave more like a very fast sound wave?

Comment: Electromagnetism holds atoms together. What would electromagnetism look like without Lorentz invariance?

Comment: Relative to neutrinos us "slow moving organisms" are actually moving close to the speed of light.

Comment: *in a world where electromagnetic waves have no speed limit and behave more like a very fast sound wave?*  The actual speed of light is order of magnitude faster than the speed of sound and there is no real comparison between these two things.  An EM wave travelling at infinite speed (not realistic) would not in any way be like a very fast sound wave.

Comment: The speed of light is a measure of the rate at which time flows.  So if there was no speed limit on light, then the flow of time would have no meaning.  Time dilation is responsible for gravity, which holds the planets, stars, etc together.  So no, if there was no speed limit then time dilation would have no meaning and life as we know it could not exist.   This is a good question.